# Who creates and amends tech logs?

Tags: easa-regulations

Is it the operator, manufacturer or the NAA?

I'm going to assume the operator does the creation and amending and only the NAA is to approve the document?

Comment: I can't answer for EASA, but my experience in north america is the OEM delivers the airplane with a chintzy set of tech logs, like note books, and the operator goes out and buys decent hard bound ones from publishers who produce that kind of stuff.  What goes in the log and how it's to be recorded is a function of local regulations, so the content and formatting just has to conform to those requirements and I've never heard of a regulator approving a tech log as a publication..